# How to find the maximum number using a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to understand how to find the maximum number using a recursive function, but I do not really understand how. Having this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    int ar[100],n,i;
    int *ptr;
    printf("Enter size of the list:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Printing the list:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }
    ptr=&ar;
    int max=maximum(ptr,n);
    printf("ma %d",max);
    return 0;
}
int maximum(int ar[], int n)
{

    int max;
    if(n+1==1)
    {
        return ar[n];
    }
    max =maximum(ar,n-1);
    return ar[n]>max?ar[n]:max;
}
```

What is it actually doing and how?
Is it correctly using pointers to point the array of integers?
I hope you can help me understand it!

Comment: `a[n]` is undefined behavior. You are reading uninitialized values.

Comment: Recursion has it's place, but be very wary of the number of times it may recurse. You are creating a separate function stack and local variables each time a recursive call is made. Think about an in-order sequence from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` and the number of separate function stacks that would be created. (yes, in reality the number will "probably" be much less, but be mindful of what could happen)

Comment: Why `if (n+1==1)` though? Apart from being harder to read, `n+1` can (theoretically) lead to overflow.

Comment: @Groo It looks like some coding puzzle for a beginner, and they are supposed to realize that `if (n + 1 == 1)` is just the same as `if (n == 0)`. There are a lot of other silly things in this code. Anyways, depth first recursion is very confusing the first time you see it. I went through the motions of a thorough explanation. I hope that helps.

Comment: @okovko: it's a weird coding puzzle since calling `maximum(ptr, n)` from main will lead to UB, as Ajay mentioned.

Comment: @Groo Well, the best way to learn about UB is to write code that invokes UB (so long as it crashes :P)

Answer (score 1):

You set aside memory for an array of 100 integers with `int ar[100]`, and you enter `n` which is set using `scanf("%d", &n)`. If you enter a number greater than 100 at this stage, your program will seg fault because your loop `for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)` will try to access `ar[100]` which is a memory access error (the highest array index available is `ar[100 - 1]`, notice that 100 - 1 < 100). Anyways, you fill `n` indices of `ar` in the loop. `ptr = &ar` just assigns the starting address of `ar` to `ptr`. By the way `ptr = ar` will work too, the `&` is not necessary. Now you can use `ptr` the same way you were using `ar`.

The easiest way to understand the recursion is to go straight to the last call of `maximum`. But first, understand that you passed `ptr` to the function which is the same as passing `ar` (remember, they are the same thing in `main` since `ptr = ar`.).

So in the last call to `maximum`, When `n + 1 == 1` (same as `n == 0`), it returns `ar[n]` which is `ar[0]`, which is first the number you entered for `'Printing the list'` (it was stored in `ar[0]`).

Now in the second last call to `maximum`, `n + 1 == 1` is false because `n = 1` so we go to `max = maximum(ar, n - 1)`. That's the result of the last call to `maximum` that I just explained, so `max` has the value of `ar[0]`. Now you have `return ar[n] > max ? ar[n] : max`, which is the same as `return ar[1] > ar[0] ? ar[1] : ar[0]`. That is the same as

```
if (ar[1] > ar[0]) {
  return ar[1];
} else {
  return ar[0];
}
```

And you can see that this returns whichever is bigger, `ar[0]` or `ar[1]`. Now for the third last call to `maximum`, `max` is the result of the second last call to `maximum`. And you can see the pattern emerge. You will return whichever is greater: `max` or `ar[n]` for all the rest of the calls to `maximum`, and by the time you get to the first call to `maximum`, you will have compared all the values in `ar` to find its maximum and return it.

Also, what Ajay said is right, `ar[n]` is accessing a value that you never initialized in your loop. You should write `int max = maximum(ptr, n - 1)` in `main` to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

My solution with tail recursion:

```
int maximum(int a[], int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return a[0];
    --n;
    return maximum(a + (a[0] < a[n]), n);
}
```

[Demo on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7vIR4k)

Comment: that doesn't work , for instance `maximum({1, 2}, 2)` returns 1

Comment: It is a very interesting way to do

Answer (score 0):

To understand how `maximum` works, just try and find some invariants in the `maximum` function

```
int maximum(int ar[], int n)
{
    int max;
    if(n==0)
    {
        return ar[n];
    }
    max =maximum(ar,n-1);
    /* at this point MAX keeps the maximum of the subarray [0..N-1] and using this 
       we try to get by induction the maximum of [1..N]. */
    return ar[n]>max?ar[n]:max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that definition :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void maximum(int nums[], int size, int index, int * max)
{
  if (index != size) {
    if (nums[index] > *max)
      *max = nums[index];
    maximum(nums, size, ++index, max);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int * nums;
  int size, i, max;

  fprintf(stderr, "Enter size of the list: "); /* stderr to flush without \n */
  if ((scanf("%d", &size) != 1) || (size <= 0)) {
    puts("wrong size");
    return 0;
  }

  if ((nums = malloc(size * sizeof(int))) == 0) {
    puts("cannot allocate nums");
    return 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    if (scanf("%d", &nums[i]) != 1) {
      puts("invalid number");
      return 0;
    }
  }

  max = nums[0];
  maximum(nums, size, 1, &max);
  free(nums);
  printf("max = %d\n", max);

  return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
% gcc -O2 -pedantic -Wall m.c
% ./a.out
Enter size of the list: 3
3
1
2
max = 3
```

*maximum* is recursive, but this is a *terminal recursion*, so the compiler can remove it to generate a loop. So *maximum* seems to be recursive as you request but the stack will not explode even with a large number :

```
% ( echo 100000000 ; yes 1 ) | ./a.out
Enter size of the list: max = 1
```

If I remove the option `-O2` the generate code uses the recursion and the stack explode :

```
% gcc -pedantic -Wall m.c
% ( echo 100000000 ; yes 1 ) | ./a.out
Enter size of the list: Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxRecursively( arr array, int index){

    int max = array.ptr[index];

    if ( index == array.length-2 ){
        return max= array.ptr[index]> array.ptr[index+1] ? array.ptr[index]:array.ptr[index+1];
    }

    return  max = max > maxRecursively(array,index+1) ? max: maxRecursively(array,index+1);
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be C language? Question is for C, and said nothing about a type "arr"